# ¿Como buscar y eliminar datos en una lista de python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

necesito que me ayuden con esto. yo tengo esta lista
 `total = ['Agustin', 'Damore', 1, 'pass1', 'Jose', 'Sanchez', 2, 'pass2']`
 los datos son completamente desconocidos necesitaría un codigo que al ingresar por ejemplo "damore" lo busque en total y borre el dato que esta antes "agustin" y los dos que le siguen "1" y "pass1" desde ya muchas gracias

```
elif op=="2":
searching = input("ingrese apellido: ")

if searching in total:
    lastname_index = total.index(searching)

name_index = lastname_index - 1
lastname_index =lastname_index
cuit_index = lastname_index + 1
key_index = lastname_index + 2

name = total[name_index]
lastname = total[lastname_index]
cuit = total[cuit_index]
key = total[key_index]
```

este fragmento se usa para buscar el lastname (posición 1 en la lista de ejemplo) en la lista "total" pero no se como hacer para que quite los datos de la lista

Comment: Hola Agustín, ¿has hecho algún intento para obtenerlo? Estaría bien que pusieses el código para decirte dónde has podido fallar, más que resolvertelo directamente.

Comment: Ese es mi problema lo traté de hacer de 1000 maneras distintas y todas tiran error, listas es algo que no domino y lo único que funciona es  
   # searching = input("ingrese apellido: ")

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar lo que intentaste?, y un ejemplo de como quieres que sea la salida del programa

Comment: La idea que nos muestres que es lo que has intentado, es para que nadie llegue a pensar que lo que buscas es que hagamos tu tarea, cosa que en general no es bien recibida y suele ser una de las causas más habituales de cierre de una pregunta. Saludos

Comment: no tiene salida solo tiene que borrar los 4 datos cada dato tiene su nombre el de la posicion 0  "agustin" se llama "name" el 1 es "damore" que seria "lastname" el 2 "1" seria "cuit" y el tres "pass1" se llama "key" lo que necesito es un input que al ingresar un dato un "lastname" lo busque en la lista total y luego elimine los datos que lo rodean los cuales serian los anterior mente dormidos. siempre en la misma posición

Comment: gracias por la recomendación... mi intención en ningún momento es que me hagan el trabajo. quiero aprender a hacerlo es por eso que consulto. lamento el malentendido

Comment: `lista.pop(indice)` elimina de la lista el elemento cuyo índice le pases como parámetro. Pero cuidado, una vez has eliminado un elemento con `pop()`, eso hará que los índices cambien para los que quedan. Lo más sencillo puede ser que elimines cuatro veces con pop el elemento en la posición `name_index`.

Comment: Si borras el nombre con `pop(name_index)`, los restantes "se mueven a la izquierda", de modo que repitiendo otra vez `pop(name_index)` borras el apellido, y repitiéndolo otra vez el "cuit", etc. Otra forma puede ser sustituir la sublista que quieres elminar por una lista vacía, así: `total[name_index:name_index+4] = []`

Comment: exacto es por eso que necesito borrar los cuatro elementos para que los parametros de busqueda queden intactos y al mismo tiempo que no muestre datos erróneos

Comment: me podrías escribir la corrección del código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pongo otra solución a tu problema para evitar repetir el código y que se eliminen los cuatro elementos que quieres.

```
total = ['Agustin', 'Damore', 1, 'pass1', 'Jose', 'Sanchez', 2, 'pass2']

indx = total.index('Damore')

del total[indx - 1:indx + 3]

print(total)  #>> Devuelve ['Jose', 'Sanchez', 2, 'pass2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar un elemento de una lista en Python solo tienes que usar el metodo remove de la siguiente manera:

```
total = ['Agustin', 'Damore', 1, 'pass1', 'Jose', 'Sanchez', 2, 'pass2']
searching = input("ingrese apellido: ")
total.remove(searching)
```

Probando en una consola interactiva el resultado es este:

```
>>> total = ['Agustin', 'Damore', 1, 'pass1', 'Jose', 'Sanchez', 2, 'pass2']
>>> total
['Agustin', 'Damore', 1, 'pass1', 'Jose', 'Sanchez', 2, 'pass2']
>>> total.remove('Damore')
>>> total
['Agustin', 1, 'pass1', 'Jose', 'Sanchez', 2, 'pass2']
```

EDIT: Adicionalmente te sugiero utilizar los metodos de las listas de python. para buscar un indice no necesitas hacer un recorrido a la lista puede usar el metodo index de las listas de Python de la siguiente manera:

```
>>> total.index('Sanchez')
4
```

EDIT 2: Perdona entendí mal la pregúnta.

En este caso lo que debes hacer es de igual forma un remove con 
name, lastname, cuit y key

Sería esto justo al final de tu código sin modificar el que ya tienes:

```
total.remove(name)
total.remove(lastname)
total.remove(cuit)
total.remove(key)
```

En caso de no necesitar usar los nombres o valores puedes usar POP y tu código podría quedar así:

```
elif op=="2":
searching = input("ingrese apellido: ")

if searching in total:
    lastname_index = total.index(searching)

total.pop(lastname_index - 1)
total.pop(lastname_index)
total.pop(lastname_index + 1)
total.pop(lastname_index + 2)
```

Espero te ayude, saludos.

Comment: Eso es lo que me mata el buscar y eliminar los otros 3

Comment: Edite la respuesta indicando la solución a tu problema,.

Comment: Si he entendido bien la pregunta, este código no devolvería lo que piden. Pasandole 'Damore' tal como lo haces con .pop, devolvería ['Damore', 'pass1', 'Sanchez', 'pass2']. Al hacer el primer .pop la lista cambiaría, por lo que estarías eliminando elementos cada dos posiciones.